# max-age doesn't work

Tags: php, http-headers, cdn

I have a PHP code that implements max-age header. I hosted the same code on different servers at different web hosts. However, I see that max-age works on one, but doesn't work on the other. I can't figure out what the problem is, since the code is the same. Does max-age header depend on anything else?

By the way, the following is the code that I've used.

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=60, public');
header('Content-type: text/html');
echo date("F j, Y - H:i:s");
```

Comment: Are you inspecting the headers you're receiving (Firebug/Chrome console Net tab)?

Comment: So actually, this could be an issue with the client, not the server. Can you test with curl on the commandline: `$ curl -iv http://example.com/`?

Comment: I don't know how to run curl (I am on a windows machine). Anyway, I checked it on web-sniffer.net and it shows the correct cache headers in the response section. However, on refresh, the date that is being returned by the php page gets updated, which means that the cache header is not honored

Comment: Some hosts have their own caches as well. They can choose to ignore your headers. What host do you have?

Comment: I posted the answer at http://serverfault.com/questions/328189/max-age-doesnt-work/328240#328240.

Comment: Please don't do that, flag for a moderator to migrate your posts.